# Understanding why and how often frames are dropped using OpenCV app on iPhone

Tags: ios, opencv, video, frames

I am creating a test harness to test the precision of various algorithms I am creating that use opencv framework in iOS.

As of right now I am more or less looking to understand if either the opencv or just the iphone is the perpetrator in the dropping of frames. And once I find out whom it is, is there a way to measure how often it is dropping frames and when it is dropping frames.

The reason I can tell is due to the set up of my test harness. I have found that the algorithm runs at about 18fps when running in real time on the phone. But I have then created a modified version of processImage() to be able to process a set of frames in png format. With this process I get about 10fps. Granted I am having to convert these frames from png to a Mat type which I know would take a significant amount of time. So I might be wrong.

Any advice on this subject is greatly appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

two useful like are [first](http://opencv.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/icvs/ICVS2013%20-%20Opencv%20for%20iOS.pdf) and [second](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ios/video_processing/video_processing.html) about ios and opencv